# How to create a snippet in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 8.1. Snippets do not trigger

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

I cannot create a working snippet in ST3 on Windows 8.1. `tabTrigger` just doesn't print anything.

For instance, I want to create a snippet `@mixin` for `.scss` files. Here is how I create it.

```
Tools > New Snippet...
```

A new untitled file is opened that contains snippet's sample. I change it to my snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
@mixin ${1:mixin-name}(${2:var}) {
    ${3:...code...}
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mix</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.scss</scope>
</snippet>
```

Then I type `Ctrl+S` and it opens a dialog window for saving the snippet. In my case it is in:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

I save it as `mixin-scss.sublime-snippet`. Then I go to `.scss` file type `mix` and tap `Tab` but nothing happens. Even if I reload ST3 it doesn't work. How to create a snippet on Windows 8.1? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a windows 8.1 issue.
Your snipped does not work on osx/linux.

Your scope is wrong. 
`text.scss` does not exists.

Replace it by `source.scss` and it works well. 
[Check gist for scopes](https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378)

Working example:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    @mixin ${1:mixin-name}(${2:var}) {
    ${3:...code...}}
    ]]>
    </content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mix</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.scss</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Twig? There is `HTML(Twig)` syntax that Twig plugin provides. What is the scope for it? `source.html`, `source.twig`, `source.html(twig)`, `source.html.twig` do not work. Gist doesn't have info too

Comment: @Green Its no supported by default in sublimetext, but there's a plugin for it: Check https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle. There's also a scopes section https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle#scopes. Consider asking a new Question, so it's easier to find an answer for some one else, who is facing the same problem.